# Why does the ES8374 have 5 pins to receive input from a microphone?

Tags: analog, audio, adc, microphone, audio-codec

I am using a ES8374 codec for an audio application. I am not able to make out how to connect my analog condenser mic (which has two pins) to the ES8374 mic pins. (Refer to pictures from the [datasheet](http://www.everest-semi.com/pdf/ES8374%20PB.pdf))

[image]

The following is the block diagram of the ES8374:

[image]

Is it to connect two mics as a differential input?
I am a beginner with audio applications.

Comment: You should include a link to the datasheet, for two reasons: 1, so we don't have to search for it ourselves, and 2, site rules require you to cite sources for potentially copyrighted material.

Comment: will keep in mind in future, someone added on my behalf. Thanks